# Hot to feed php function

Tags: php, xml

Hi I am try to display icecat product data and I am a complete php newbie, I have tracked down a code snippet that I believe should do the job, It says that It requires that you feed the function with an EAN product number.

Could someone please give me an example of what this means as I have no idea, here is a EAN Product number EAN/UPC code:0885909481842

Here is the snippet code I am trying to use.

```
    function getICEcatProductSpecs($ean, $drawdescription = 0, $drawpicture = 0)
{   
// Username and password for usage with ICEcat
$username = "Your ICEcat username goes here";
$password = "Your ICEcat password goes here";

// Return 0 and exit function if no EAN available
if($ean == null)
{
return 0;
}

// Get the product specifications in XML format
$context = stream_context_create(array(
'http' => array(
'header' => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($username.":".$password)
)
));
$data = file_get_contents('http://data.icecat.biz/xml_s3/xml_server3.cgi?ean_upc='.$ean.';lang=nl;output=productxml', false, $context);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);

// Create arrays of item elements from the XML feed
$productPicture = $xml->xpath("//Product");
$productDescription = $xml->xpath("//ProductDescription");
$categories = $xml->xpath("//CategoryFeatureGroup");
$spec_items = $xml->xpath("//ProductFeature");

//Draw product specifications table if any specs available for the product
if($spec_items != null)
{
$categoryList = array();
foreach($categories as $categoryitem) {
$catId = intval($categoryitem->attributes());
$titleXML = new SimpleXMLElement($categoryitem->asXML());
$title = $titleXML->xpath("//Name");
$catName = $title[0]->attributes();
//echo $catId . $catName['Value']. "<br />";
$categoryList[$catId] = $catName['Value'];
}

$specs = "<table class='productspecs'>";
$i = 0;

$drawnCategories = array();

foreach($spec_items as $item) {
$specValue = $item->attributes();
$titleXML = new SimpleXMLElement($item->asXML());
$title = $titleXML->xpath("//Name");
$specName = $title[0]->attributes();
$specCategoryId = intval($specValue['CategoryFeatureGroup_ID']);

if($specName['Value'] != "Source data-sheet")
{
$class = $i%2==0?"odd":"even";
$specs .= "<tr class='".$class."'>
<td>
<table>";
if(!in_array($specCategoryId, $drawnCategories))
{
$specs .= " <tr class='speccategory'>
<th><h3>".$categoryList[$specCategoryId]."</h3></th>
</tr>";
$drawnCategories[$i] = $specCategoryId;
}
$specs .= " <tr>
<th>".utf8_decode($specName['Value']).":</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>";
if($specValue['Presentation_Value'] == "Y")
{
$specs .= "Ja <img src='".SCRIPT_ROOT."images/check_green.png' alt='Ja' />";
}
else if($specValue['Presentation_Value'] == "N")
{
$specs .= "Nee <img src='".SCRIPT_ROOT."images/check_red.png' alt='Nee' />";
}
else
{
$specs .= str_replace('\n', '<br />', utf8_decode($specValue['Presentation_Value']));
}
$specs .= "</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>";
}
$i++;
}
$specs .= "</table>";

//Draw product description and link to manufacturer if available
if( $drawdescription != 0)
{
foreach($productDescription as $item) {
$productValues = $item->attributes();
if($productValues['URL'] != null)
{
$specs .= "<p id='manufacturerlink'><a href='".$productValues['URL']."'>Productinformation from manufacturer</a></p>";
}
if($productValues['LongDesc'] != null)
{
$description = utf8_decode(str_replace('\n', '', $productValues['LongDesc']));
$description = str_replace('<b>', '<strong>', $description);
$description = str_replace('<B>', '<strong>', $description);
$description = str_replace('</b>', '</strong>', $description);
$specs .= "<p id='manudescription'>".$description."</p>";
}
}
}

//Draw product picture if available
if( $drawdescription != 0)
{
foreach($productPicture as $item) {
$productValues = $item->attributes();
if($productValues['HighPic'] != null)
{
$specs .= "<div id='manuprodpic'><img src='".$productValues['HighPic']."' alt='' /></div>";
}
}
}
return $specs;
}
else
{
return 0;
}
}
```

Any advice will be very appreciated thx in advance Peter

Comment: Sorry, but this is offtopic. We're here to help with programming problems. Basic "how to code" stuff is beyond the scope of the site - we're not here to teach you how to read code. You need to do this on your own.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that it's saying that if you call this function you should pass EAN parameter to it, like this:

```
getICEcatProductSpecs("0885909481842", 0, 0);
```